# Matching the first occurrence only of a string then adding N lines awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Hi would like extract  N number of lines after matching  the first  incidence of  a string printing the N lines following  using awk.  The string is repeated a number of times in the file I am processing . I have tried using this command:

`'c&&c--;/XCHT/{c=10}'`

This prints all incidences of the match + 10 lines. I have seen various versions of this command after extensive searches but all versions produce largely the same result  as below. I have looked around to find  . I would like some tips on how to modify this command to achieve the result

The result of the match I would like to achieve is as follows

```
| XCHT            |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 9  |
| 大枣dazao       | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |
```

A section of the file looks like this:

```
## XCHT
| XCHT            |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 9  |
| 大枣dazao       | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |


## XCHT+CM

|                 |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 干姜ganjiang    | 9  |
| 五味子wuweizi   | 9  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |

## XCHT+TM


| XCHT+TM                 |    |
|-----------------        |----|
| 柴胡chaihu              | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin            | 9  |
| 法天花粉tianhuafen      | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang          | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia           | 12 |
| 大枣dazao               | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao         | 9  |
|                         |    |
|                         |    |
 

| XCHT-HQin+FL    |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄茯苓fuling    | 12 |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 9  |
| 大枣dazao       | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |
## XCHT-DZ+ML

| XCHT-DZ+ML      |     |
|-----------------|-----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 12  |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 4.5 |
| 法半夏banxia    | 6   |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 4.5 |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 4.5 |
| 牡蛎 muli       | 6   |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 4.5 |
|                 |     |
|                 |     |
```

The result of the  command `'c&&c--;/XCHT/{c=10}'` on the file

```
| XCHT            |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 9  |
| 大枣dazao       | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |

| XCHT            |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 干姜ganjiang    | 9  |
| 五味子wuweizi   | 9  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |



| XCHT+TM                 |    |
|-----------------        |----|
| 柴胡chaihu              | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin            | 9  |
| 法天花粉tianhuafen      | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang          | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia           | 12 |
| 大枣dazao               | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao         | 9  |
|                         |    |
|                         |    |

| XCHT-DZ+ML      |     |
|-----------------|-----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 12  |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 4.5 |
| 法半夏banxia    | 6   |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 4.5 |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 4.5 |
| 牡蛎 muli       | 6   |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 4.5 |
|                 |     |
|                 |     |

| Xiao Chaihi Tang -HQ+BS |    |
|-------------------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu              | 24 |
| 白芍baishao             | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia            | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang          | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia           | 9  |
| 大枣dazao               | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao         | 9
```

The tables are a bit wonky as a result of copying them to the webpage. Any help of advice will be much appreciated .

Comment: Are the `|` part of the file or did you add them here only?

Comment: And does it need to be `awk`? If you have GNU `grep` you could just do `grep -m1 -A10 XCHT`.

Comment: the  ```|``` are part of the file used as table separators

Comment: Are those lines starting with `##`  **really** present above some blocks in your input, sometimes with a blank line after them, other times not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to handle this is to exit when `c` goes back to 0:

```
c { print; if (--c == 0) exit }; /XCHT/{c=10}
```

or more concisely,

```
c; c && !--c { exit }; /XCHT/{c=10}
```

GNU `grep` can do something similar:

```
grep -m1 -A10 XCHT
```

(but this will show the first line matching “XCHT” as well).

Comment: Thanks Stephen that did the trick . I had an idea that it might be something to do with ```exit``` but had no idea where to put it . I admit I only vaguely understand the use of ```c``` in an awk program . Do you have any tips for understanding it' usage,  It does not seem to be well documented in any of the books or web resources I've come across.

Comment: @ajr_chm `c` is just a variable, it could be named `count` or `fluffy_bunny` or anything else but `c` is a pretty common name for a counter variable. See [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105) for more info on this and other awk idioms.

Comment: Why is the ```c;``` present in the beginning of this command but not in any of the commands in the link . Something to do with the  presence of ```exit``` ?

Comment: @ajr_chm yes; in the linked examples, the conditions determine whether to print, but here there is one condition to print (`c`), and another to exit. `c;` is equivalent to `c { print };`, or more explicitly `{ if (c != 0) print };` (treating `c` as a purely numeric variable).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to print a blank-line-separated record that just happens to be 10 lines long. Instead of counting lines and hard-coding how many lines you think are in a record, with awk you can just set `RS` to a null string to simply deal with such records no matter their length.

If those lines starting with `##` aren't really present in your input then all you need is:

```
awk -v RS= '/XCHT/{print; exit}' file
```

otherwise if those lines really are present then we can remove them with a sub():

```
$ awk -v RS= '{sub(/##[^\n]*(\n|$)/,"")} /XCHT/{print; exit}' file
| XCHT            |    |
|-----------------|----|
| 柴胡chaihu      | 24 |
| 黄芩huangqin    | 9  |
| 法半夏banxia    | 12 |
| 生姜shengjiang  | 9  |
| 刺五加ciwujia   | 9  |
| 大枣dazao       | 6  |
| 炙甘草zhigancao | 9  |
|                 |    |
|                 |    |
```